# Wordpress Addthis Share Buttons - sharing doesn't work, 400 bad request

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, addthis

I use AddThis Share Buttons on my site (this add-on was installed in ready-made WP theme). I have four social buttons: FB, Twitter, VK and LinkedIn.

The problem is that when you try to share the post, the page gets error 400. In different browsers different buttons **doesn't work**: Chrome 46 — twitter, vk, linkedin; FF 42 — vk, linkedin; IE11 — all buttons work (:D)

I think it's because of too long request - but I can be wrong. How to struggle it? Maybe someone had similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

If the addon was installed by default in the theme, they may have used the addthis API. In that case, error 400 means a missing/invalid parameter or an exceeded rate limit for that particular API call.

For more details have a look at http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381264-addthis-analytics-api

Additionally, if you can post your site URL, it will help us to find the problem causing api call url

Comment: site's url is http://thewall.by/, maybe it helps, buttons are at the bottom of every single post